# Blender2Xplane texturing?

Tags: texturing, uv

I attempted to model my own plane to use inside the Xplane flight sim. I have done everything correctly inside Blender and Xplane's Plane Maker. The plane flies with the model inside the program, but the only part I cannot figure out is how to get the image texture to show up. I've watched danklaue's youtube tutorials, yet all he does to accomplish this is assign the texture to the UV unwrap. I assume this problem might be solved by linking the texture to the UV unwrap without nodes, but even if this happened to be the solution, I don't know how to do this in Blender 2.80. I don't think Eevee's texture editor (with nodes OFF) allows you to have an image for the base color, and Cycles only uses nodes in the first place. If anyone knows this solution please let me know. I've noticed the little documentation on this for the present Xplane2Blender so I doubt many people know how to do this. I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Ted. I'm the developer of XPlane2Blender. The best place for this type of question is GitHub's issues page.

XPlane2Blender used to have a feature where it would use a material's texture slots to automatically fill in the TEXTURE path. Blender 2.80 removed Texture Slots so now while a similar feature is being implemented, we're just having people put in the relative file path by hand. Remember not to use spaces. You'll find that in the OBJ settings.

[image]

In this image, some Empty or Mesh or other Blender Object has been marked as exportable (or "Root Object" in old 2.79 UI). The name is my_example_object, and its TEXTURE is `my_texture.png`

XPlane2Blender doesn't check that this file exists so that is up to you.

Read the release notes pages for recent releases of XPlane2Blender as it is currently the best source of documentation on new features.